# Compatibility of micro_ros_arduino with platformio

Tags: ros2, microcontroller, micro-ros

Most of my friends use the Arduino IDE to work with microROS. But I prefer working with PlatformIO on vscode. However as you know, there can be a little bit of differences in the micro_ros_platformio and micro_ros_arduino. The way I undestand it, micro_ros_platformio just provides more flexibility during the build process. I just wanted to know if micro_ros_arduino library is fully compatible with PlatformIO or if there's anything else I should know of?